# Chase player with camera in AndEngine and limit world's bounds

Tags: android, opengl-es, 2d, andengine

Using AndEngine for Android, I would like to have my scene look like this:

[image]

The red box is the world which must be limited to a given size, say `2000px*450px`.

The blue box is the `Camera`, which is limited as well (as usual), for example to `750px*450px`.

For the whole scene, I have a background image that is exactly `450px` high. So my `Camera` can be scaled to whatever size is appropriate, but the background must exactly fit to the height. The width of the `Camera` may be variable.

The player (circle) must always be in the center (horizontally) but may not leave the world's boundaries.

To achieve this, I've tried adding two types of sizes:

- camera size (`CAMERA_WIDTH`, `CAMERA_HEIGHT`)
- world size (`WORLD_WIDTH`, `WORLD_HEIGHT`)

And this function was to add boundaries to the world so that the physics engine prevents the player from leaving those boundaries:

```
private void createWorldBoundaries() {
    Body body;
    final Rectangle wall_top = new Rectangle(0, WORLD_HEIGHT-5, WORLD_WIDTH, 10, mVertexManager);
    final Rectangle wall_bottom = new Rectangle(0, 5, WORLD_WIDTH, 10, mVertexManager);
    final Rectangle wall_left = new Rectangle(5, 0, 10, WORLD_HEIGHT, mVertexManager);
    final Rectangle wall_right = new Rectangle(WORLD_WIDTH-5, 0, 10, WORLD_HEIGHT, mVertexManager);
    body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(mPhysicsWorld, wall_top, BodyType.StaticBody, new PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f));
    wall_top.setUserData(body);
    body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(mPhysicsWorld, wall_bottom, BodyType.StaticBody, new PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f));
    wall_bottom.setUserData(body);
    body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(mPhysicsWorld, wall_left, BodyType.StaticBody, new PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f));
    wall_left.setUserData(body);
    body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(mPhysicsWorld, wall_right, BodyType.StaticBody, new PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f));
    wall_right.setUserData(body);
    attachChild(wall_top);
    attachChild(wall_bottom);
    attachChild(wall_left);
    attachChild(wall_right);
}
```

<strike>But this is not working, unfortunately.</strike> (see edit)

Setting the camera to chase the player has the wrong result for me: The player does really stay in the center of the screen all time, but I want the player only to stay in the center horizontally, not vertically.

What am I doing wrong and what can I change? And the basic question is: How can I make the world wider than the camera view, while the height is equal to the camera view. The result should be that you can horizontally walk through your world (moving camera) and you can always see the full height.

**Edit:**

As you define the coordinates of the `Rectangle`'s center and not its top-left corner, you have to do it like this, it seems:

```
final Rectangle wall_top = new Rectangle(WORLD_WIDTH/2, WORLD_HEIGHT-1, WORLD_WIDTH, 2, mVertexManager);
final Rectangle wall_bottom = new Rectangle(WORLD_WIDTH/2, FIELD_BASELINE_Y+1, WORLD_WIDTH, 2, mVertexManager);
final Rectangle wall_left = new Rectangle(1, WORLD_HEIGHT/2, 2, WORLD_HEIGHT, mVertexManager);
final Rectangle wall_right = new Rectangle(WORLD_WIDTH-1, WORLD_HEIGHT/2, 2, WORLD_HEIGHT, mVertexManager);
```

However, I had found the other solution in several tutorials. Are these authors not testing their code before writing the tutorials or did the behaviour change from GLES1 to GLES2 or with any recent version?

Comment: Long question, and long answer below. The answer should be simple as: Use `SmoothCamera` instead of `Camera`, and setup bound (use `setBounds()`) to meet your world dimension. You can setup the camera move velocity (use `setMaxVelocity()`) to make it faster than the velocity of your chased entity, so the chased entity will stay in center unless the chased entity is closed to the bound. You can also temporarily disable the bound (use `setBoundsEnabled(false)`) to see how the bounds affect the chasing function.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Although this comment is shorter, it does not add anything to the answer below, does it? Rather, why should you use `SmoothCamera` at all if you plan to make it faster than the chased entity? In this case, it will be equal to the `BoundCamera`, won't it?

Comment: @MarcoW. you are right with this one, as long as you don't use the max velocity as a real limit you get a `ZoomCamera` and until you don't want to use the zoom, you get a `BoundCamera`. the SmoothCamera adds just some extra calculation into the onUpdate to calculate the current velocity and limit it to the max velocity. as well does the zoom camera some extra calculation to limit the zoom to the max and min zoom factor

Comment: @MarcoW. If I understood your question correctly (if I didn't, you really can ignore my comment above), you need to setup zoom factor on your camera because you said 'The width of the Camera may be variable', and that's why I suggested using SmoothCamera. (Bounds + zoom + move speed control)

Comment: Ah, now I see what you were referring to, and for that, your answer is perfectly correct. But what I meant was something different: AndEngine usually adds white/black bars at the left and right (or top/bottom) if your device's ratio does not match the one set in your app. But I would like my `Camera` to just show more of the world (horizontally) and thus fill the bars with content. You see, only the height is fixed for my application, but if the device has some unused space on the left and right side, it may just widen the `Camera`'s view.

Comment: you should get rid of the black border left/right or btm/top with `FillResolutionPolicy`, instead of RatioResolutionPolicy

Comment: `FillResolutionPolicy` is not what I need. More than that, it is not what most people need. With that setting, the screen is filled (what I want), but this is achieved by streching (what nobody wants) everything to a wrong ratio. Assuming we have set `800` as the `Camera`'s height and a device has 800 as its height. Perfect. But the device has a width of `420` while we did choose `480`. What this policy does is stretching the same screen section from `420` to `480`. Better would be if additional areas are shown at left/right to fill the `480`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i think your question about the world boundaries is self answered, isn't it?

**PhysicsWorld Boundaries**

for further research you can download nicolas' AndEngine Examples App from the Play Store and look up the different examples here (GLES_2, didn't look for AnchorCenter yet): https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/tree/GLES2/src/org/andengine/examples

Taken from the PhysicsExample, the code for the rectangles should look like this, if the bounds are set to the camera bounds. in your case, you can extend width like you want (3 times CAMERA_WIDTH?)

```
    final Rectangle ground = new Rectangle(0, CAMERA_HEIGHT - 2, WORLD_WIDTH, 2, vertexBufferObjectManager);
    final Rectangle roof = new Rectangle(0, 0, WORLD_WIDTH, 2, vertexBufferObjectManager);
    final Rectangle left = new Rectangle(0, 0, 2, CAMERA_HEIGHT, vertexBufferObjectManager);
    final Rectangle right = new Rectangle(WORLD_WIDTH - 2, 0, 2, CAMERA_HEIGHT, vertexBufferObjectManager);
```

**Camera following player**
for the Camera to follow your player, you can lookup the code of the BoundCameraExample https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/examples/BoundCameraExample.java

the interesting part for you should be the addFace method at the bottom

```
private void addFace(final float pX, final float pY) {
    final FixtureDef objectFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(1, 0.5f, 0.5f);
final AnimatedSprite face = new AnimatedSprite(pX, pY, this.mBoxFaceTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()).animate(100);
final Body body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, face, BodyType.DynamicBody, objectFixtureDef);
this.mScene.attachChild(face);
this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(face, body, true, true));

this.mBoundChaseCamera.setChaseEntity(face);
}
```

this method creates a physics body + sprite for "your player" (in this case, a boxed face) and sets the sprite as a chaseEntity for the camera to follow. Since the camera has bounds, that it can't exceed and your camera will have the height of your PhysicWorld boundaries, you can use this to let your camera follow the player in x, but not in y direction.

if you (i don't know why) don't want to use these boundaries, you can overwrite the onUpdate method of your Sprite and re-locate your camera only in x-direction, instead of xy coords

```
face.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {
   @Override
   public void onUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed) {
      float[] coord = face.getSceneCenterCoordinates();
      this.mBoundChaseCamera.setCenter(sceneCenterCoordinates[0], CAMERA_Y_POSITION);
   }
}
```

where the `CAMERA_Y_POSITION` is a static final field with the y-position.

I hope this answers your question(s). :-)

edit: oops, i forgot to mention, how to achieve the camera to be bound and i will edit the world width above:

```
    this.mBoundChaseCamera.setBounds(0, 0,
            WORLD_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
```

all settings are like your image given (except the exact position of the face, that has to be given to the `addFace(px, py)`)

**Edit: Difference between scene boundaries in Andengine GLES2 vs GLES2-AnchorCenter**

As far as i understood the question, i thought you would use GLES2, i thought of the (older) default GLES2 branch of AndEngine and posted the boundaries. As you found out yourself before and stated in the comments, you use another approach to set the rectangles - where you need to set the rectangles center as pX and pY. The reason for this is in fact, that with the AnchorCenter branch, you won't set the upper left position of an entity anymore and instead use it's center position.

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly! :) There's just one thing: Your code for the `Rectangle`s (ground, roof, left, right) is wrong, isn't it? It seems to suffer from the same problems that I explained in my question (and later corrected). If you want the roof to go from `0` to `WORLD_WIDTH` you can't set `x` to `0`. You have to set it to `WORLD_WIDTH/2` as AndEngine expects coordinates for the `Body`'s center, not its left edge.

Comment: hmm, imho that's not true - see the [PhysicsExample](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/examples/PhysicsExample.java), given by nicolas and working on my phone - the example should fit your needs perfectly, except that their worldWidth = cameraWidth, while yours is larger. i'm not quite sure why you are experiencing this issue - do you use anchorCenter branch? if you are on GLES2 your initial post swapped the top/bottom bar, bc the 0/0 position is top/left (while in anchorCenter it's bottom/left), but that should not be the fault.

Comment: i'm still thinking over it, and i can't imagine, why your boundary code is working and the one from the example is not - cracks my head a little :-( but as long, as it's working and you are fine with it, it's probably ok ;-)

Comment: Ah, great, this is the reason, of course :) Compare https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/examples/PhysicsExample.java with https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2-AnchorCenter/src/org/andengine/examples/PhysicsExample.java

Comment: i'll edit my answer again, to fit your question and mention the AnchorBranch issue ;-)